# SQL Statement Help - Select latest Order for each Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Say I have 2 tables: Customers and Orders. A Customer can have many Orders.

Now, I need to show any Customers with his latest Order. This means if a Customer has more than one Orders, show only the Order with the latest Entry Time.

This is how far I managed on my own:

```
SELECT a.*, b.Id
FROM Customer a INNER JOIN Order b ON b.CustomerID = a.Id
ORDER BY b.EntryTime DESC
```

This of course returns all Customers with one or more Orders, showing the latest Order first for each Customer, which is not what I wanted. My mind was stuck in a rut at this point, so I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

For some reason, I *think* I need to use the MAX syntax somewhere, but it just escapes me right now.

**UPDATE:** After going through a few answers here (there's a lot!), I realized I made a mistake: I meant **any** Customer with his latest record. That means if he does not have an Order, then I do not need to list him.

**UPDATE2:** Fixed my own SQL statement, which probably caused no end of confusion to others.

Comment: Your customer table in this example has an OrderId. Is that right?

Comment: If your Customer table has an OrderID your question does not make sense. If it were true, you would be saying that every order has a different customer. Are you sure your Order table does not have a CustomerID?

Comment: @Martin: ouch, you're right! Man, My mind is really out of it today. :/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you do want to use MAX() as you don't want to group the OrderID. What you need is an ordered sub query with a SELECT TOP 1.

```
select * 
from Customers 
    inner join Orders 
        on Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
        and OrderID = (
            SELECT TOP 1 subOrders.OrderID 
            FROM Orders subOrders 
            WHERE subOrders.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
            ORDER BY subOrders.OrderDate DESC
        )
```

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is the most correct one so far, the only mistake is that you did not sort the date in descending order. Not to mentioned the most elegant. :) Thanks!

Comment: I did do the ordering at first, then I confused myself and thought you wanted the oldest order. I've now updatd my example to be correct.

Comment: IMO a simple max and group by is sufficient, which I posted as a separate answer below.  But happy to learn why that doesn't work.  Here is the query:

select c.customer_id, max(o.order_date) from customers c left join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id group by c.customer_id;

Comment: @AmrinderArora Your query doesn't return the required results. I've made a comment against your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this should do it:

```
SELECT X.*, Y.LatestOrderId
FROM Customer X
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT A.Customer, MAX(A.OrderID) LatestOrderId
  FROM Order A
  JOIN (
    SELECT Customer, MAX(EntryTime) MaxEntryTime FROM Order GROUP BY Customer
  ) B ON A.Customer = B.Customer AND A.EntryTime = B.MaxEntryTime
  GROUP BY Customer
) Y ON X.Customer = Y.Customer
```

This assumes that two orders for the same customer may have the same EntryTime, which is why `MAX(OrderID)` is used in subquery `Y` to ensure that it only occurs once per customer. The `LEFT JOIN` is used because you stated you wanted to show all customers - if they haven't got any orders, then the LatestOrderId will be `NULL`.

Hope this helps!

--

UPDATE :-) This shows only customers with orders:

```
SELECT A.Customer, MAX(A.OrderID) LatestOrderId
FROM Order A
JOIN (
  SELECT Customer, MAX(EntryTime) MaxEntryTime FROM Order GROUP BY Customer
) B ON A.Customer = B.Customer AND A.EntryTime = B.MaxEntryTime
GROUP BY Customer
```

Comment: This solution is much faster than the one which was selected by the OP.

Comment: This is the better solution as it calculates all the necessary data up front rather than in individually correlated records.

Answer (score 6):

While I see that you've already accepted an answer, I think this one is a bit more intuitive:

```sql
select      a.*
           ,b.Id
 
from       customer a
   
inner join Order b
on         b.CustomerID = a.Id
  
where      b.EntryTime = ( select max(EntryTime)
                           from   Order
                           where  a.Id = b.CustomerId
                         );
```

`a.Id = b.CustomerId` because you want the max `EntryTime` of all orders (in `b`) for the customer (`a.Id`).

I would have to run something like this through an execution plan to see the difference in execution, but where the TOP function is done after-the-fact and that using `order by` can be expensive, I believe that using `max(EntryTime)` would be the best way to run this.

Comment: I tried your query, and I find it returning the same result. Nice! I won't switch my answer at the moment though, there's a few other answers here I wanted to test. But, I'll up-vote your answer for now. :)

Comment: Surely that sub query's where clause should be CustomerId = a.Id?

Answer (score 4):

This query is much faster than the accepted answer :

```
SELECT c.id as customer_id, 
    (SELECT co.id FROM customer_order co WHERE 
    co.customer_id=c.id 
    ORDER BY some_date_column DESC limit 1) as last_order_id
    FROM customer c
```

Comment: This is indeed faster. I have record of 50k+ and this query completes at around 8secs compared to the accepted answer which runs for 15mins and still not done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a window function.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*, b.*,
               ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.orderdate DESC,
                b.ID DESC) rn
          FROM customer a, ORDER b
         WHERE a.ID = b.custid)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

For each customer (a.id) it sorts all orders and discards everything but the latest.
ORDER BY clause includes both order date and entry id, in case there are multiple orders on the same date.

Generally, window functions are much faster than any look-ups using MAX() on large number of records.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Cust.*, Ord.*
FROM Customers cust INNER JOIN Orders ord ON cust.ID = ord.CustID
WHERE ord.OrderID = 
    (SELECT MAX(OrderID) FROM Orders WHERE Orders.CustID = cust.ID)
```

Comment: You are getting the order with the Max OrderID and not the Max EntryTime which may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT
  a.*
FROM
  Customer a
    INNER JOIN Order b
      ON a.OrderID = b.Id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, max(EntryTime) as EntryTime FROM Order b GROUP BY Id) met
          ON
            b.EntryTime = met.EntryTime and b.Id = met.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I haven't seen above yet:

```
SELECT
     C.*,
     O1.ID
FROM
     dbo.Customers C
INNER JOIN dbo.Orders O1 ON
     O1.CustomerID = C.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Orders O2 ON
     O2.CustomerID = C.ID AND
     O2.EntryTime > O1.EntryTime
WHERE
     O2.ID IS NULL
```

This (as well as the other solutions I believe) assumes that no two orders for the same customer can have the exact same entry time. If that's a concern then you would have to make a choice as to what determines which one is the "latest". If that's a concern post a comment and I can expand the query if needed to account for that.

The general approach of the query is to find the order for a customer where there is not another order for the same customer with a later date. It is then the latest order by definition. This approach often gives better performance then the use of derived tables or subqueries.

Comment: I have tested this query, and it works, like the other two answers so far. Would you mind adding how you might handle 2 orders with the exact same entry time?

Comment: Interesting. Wouldn't this get exponentially slower for each extra order that a customer has as the database will need to join each order to every other order?

Answer (score 0):

A simple max and "group by" is sufficient.

```
select c.customer_id, max(o.order_date)
from customers c
inner join orders o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id;
```

No subselect needed, which slows things down.

Comment: This doesn't return the columns the question asked for. They asked for the ID of the order not the date it was placed. They also want to exclude customers with no order.

Comment: @MartinBrown Thanks. the exclusion problem is easily fixed by changing left join to inner join, but I agree, the ID of the order would need a different take.  I will think about that part.  Thanks.