# Select all customers and their last order Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql

hei,

Using Linq to SQL (ala NorthWind database for example):
How to select all customers and the latest order for each of them. The customers who have not placed order should be also in the result. 
The last order could be by ID (ID is incremental) or Timestamp (DateTime field).

similar to this [SQL Statement Help - Select latest Order for each Customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331367/sql-statement-help-select-latest-order-for-each-customer) but done in LINQ.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there's a foreign-key relationship between Customers & Orders, something like this sghould work:

```
from c in db.Customers
select new 
       { 
         Customer = c,
         LastOrder = c.Orders.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Timestamp).First();
       };
```

Comment: Hei, this works. But LastOrder contains just the Timestamp, i'd like to get whole object for the Order. Any ideas?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: D'Oh... My mistake... It's been fixed.