# SQL: Order by date and distinct Number without losing fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My knowledge about SQL is not the best but I need a quick solution for this. I have a table

```
number     | date       | text

1          | 2018-01-13 | A

2          | 2018-01-15 | B

1          | 2018-02-15 | C
```

Now I need to remove the duplicate value "number" in the output(select) based on the date. It should look like this:

```
number     | date       | text

2          | 2018-01-15 | B

1          | 2018-02-15 | C
```

I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT number, date ORDER BY date DESC FROM table
```

The problem is that I now miss the field "text" in the output. I also tried

```
SELECT * DISTINCT(SELECT * number ORDER BY(date) DESC) FROM table
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - Select newest record when there's a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515684/sql-select-newest-record-when-theres-a-duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it using below query:

```
SELECT t1.number, t1.date, t1.text
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT number, MAX(date) AS max_date
     FROM yourTable
     GROUP BY number
) t2
    ON t1.number = t2.number AND
       t1.date = t2.max_date;
```

Comment: What is the "Train" doing?

Comment: It was by mistake

Comment: It worked too! Thanks for your answer! I just had to change the last 'r =r.date' to '= r.MaxDate'. No idea why..

Comment: @ user3772108, as column alias name is "max_date", we need to use it in JOIN... Thanks

Comment: Oh i missed that. Thanks

Comment: Since I had to-do that for SSIS this was the solution that was supported.

Answer (score 4):

One option uses `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT number, date, text
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I got a bit confused. Where do i have to add my "table" in this statement?

Comment: You need to add a `FROM` clause to the inner `SELECT` query

Comment: @user3772108 I neglected to add a `FROM` clause to the inner query.

Comment: Nice solution and thanks again, but unfortunately not supported by SSIS VS 2008.

Comment: @user3772108 `ROW_NUMBER` is definitely supported by SQL Server 2008 ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)).  I didn't see that you tagged with 2005.  If you are really using this old database then you should go with the accepted answer.  Few people are using a version of SQL Server which does not support `ROW_NUMBER` these days.

Comment: I'm pretty sure support for Windows Functions began with SS 2005.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, the SQL Server does support it, but not the SSIS Solution I created. When I used the function I got a error message. On the server I could use the statement. But not in the SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

use below query this will work for ur requirement

SELECT number, date, text
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM test
) t
WHERE rn = 1;

Answer (score 0):

It can be done just using window functions:

```
create table #TEST ([NUMBER] int, [DATE] date, [TEXT] char(1))

insert into #TEST values (1, '2018-01-13', 'A'), (2, '2018-01-15', 'B'), (1, '2018-02-15', 'C')

SELECT DISTINCT [NUMBER]
    , FIRST_VALUE([DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY [NUMBER] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS [DATE]
    , FIRST_VALUE([TEXT]) OVER (PARTITION BY [NUMBER] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS [TEXT]
 FROM #TEST
```