# Get last entry from each user in database

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a Postgresql database, and I'm having trouble getting my query right, even though this seems like a common problem.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
   account_id   INTEGER,
   order_id     INTEGER,
   ts           TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
)
```

Everytime there is a new order, I use it to link the `account_id` and `order_id`.

Now my problem is that I want to get a list that has the last order (by looking at `ts`) for each account.

For example, if my data is:

```
account_id    order_id            ts
         5         178        July 1
         5         129        July 6
         4         190        July 1
         4         181        July 9
         3         348        July 1
         3         578        July 4
         3         198        July 1
         3         270       July 12
```

Then I'd like the query to return only the last row for each account:

```
account_id    order_id            ts
         5         129        July 6
         4         181        July 9
         3         270       July 12
```

I've tried `GROUP BY account_id`, and I can use that to get the `MAX(ts)` for each account, but then I have no way to get the associated `order_id`. I've also tried sub-queries, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Thanks!

Comment: You must have some primary key so use ´LIMIT 1´ and ´ORDER BY id DESC´. It reverses the order and limits it to 1 ( so the highest id is first result, limit then only takes this 1 result).

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331367/sql-statement-help-select-latest-order-for-each-customer

Comment: @Rajat I don't want just one row, I want a row for each account_id.

Comment: @Janis Thanks, but that answer is joining two tables. I only have one table. Also, I'm using Postgresql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select distinct on (account_id) *
from orders
order by account_id, ts desc
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT:

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for ORDER BY (see above). Note that the "first row" of each set is unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row appears first.

Comment: Excellent! Works great! Thanks!

I'd even used DISTINCT before, but didn't know about the ON keyword.

Comment: Just a note: apparently `DISTINCT ON (expression)` is a Postgresql thing. It's not standard SQL. Still the best answer though, since I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 2):

The `row_number()` window function can help:

```
select account_id, order_id, ts
  from (select account_id, order_id, ts,
               row_number() over(partition by account_id order by ts desc) as rn
          from tbl) t
 where rn = 1
```